# How to declare getAttribute function type in typescript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I am using typescript of nestjs with xpath module.
But since xpath module types doesn't exist @types/xpath, I declared my own xpath types as below.

```
import * as xpath from 'xpath';

export class XmlParserService {

  private query(q: string): Array<Node | string> {
    return xpath.useNamespaces(this.namespaces)(q, this.parsedXml);
  }
```

I declared xpath types in my main directory.

```
// ./src/@types/xpath/index.d.ts

declare module 'xpath' {
  type SelectedValue = Node | string;

  interface XPathSelect {
    (expression: string, node?: Node): Array<SelectedValue>;

    (expression: string, node: Node, single: true): SelectedValue | undefined;
  }

  export const select: XPathSelect;

  export function useNamespaces(namespaceMap: {
    [name: string]: string;
  }): XPathSelect;
}
```

When I use this query function, and this returns element object. 
Therefore I can use getAttribute and ownerDocument.

However, it gives an typescript error.

> Error:(104, 19) TS2339: Property 'ownerDocument' does not exist on
> type 'string | Node'.   Property 'ownerDocument' or 'getAttribute'
> does not exist on type 'string'.

```
  const currentNode = this.query(currentNodeQuery)[0];
  
  const idAttribute = currentNode.getAttribute('ID') ? 'ID' : 'Id';

  const ownerD = currentNode.ownerDocument
```

How can I declare more for this case? Thank you for reading it.

Comment: What is *"But since xpath module types doesn't declare or incorrect with other module types..."* meant to mean? Also, you've mentioned `@types/xpath`, but I don't see that package (`npm install @types/xpath` fails, and it's not [here](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types/xpath/) or [here](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types/xpath.d.ts)). The `xpath` module defines its *own* types in `xpath/xpath.d.ts`, as we can [see here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/dt/search?search=xpath).

Comment: @T.J. Crowder Thank you for reply.  I mean I want to declare my own types for "xpath" module. So I made ./src/@types/xpath in my local directory outside of node_modules folder. But I think my types is not enought for sub functions or field. And I don'k know how can I declare for "getAttribute or ownerDocument".